# how to handle the below data

Tags: ios, iphone, json

The problwm what iam facing is ..when ever iam passing the values like array inside the dictionyy..it is showing me the error -1005 connection was lost..and when ever i dont pass the values the response is getting successfully created but inthe server side database the ofiice price details and office contact information and office document is not saving ..can any one help me how to handle thanks in advance

```
 [
   {
 "OfficePrice": [
  {
    "office": 1,
    "making_charge": 1,
    "wastage": 1,
    "weight_by": 1,
    "credit_period": 1,
    "cartage_price_type": null,
    "cartage_price": null,
    "diamond_price": 1,
    "amethyst_price": 1,
    "amber_price": 1,
    "sapphire_price": 1,
    "emerald_price": null,
    "ruby_price": null,
    "id": 1,
    "createdAt": "2016-04-15T08:41:08.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-04-16T14:18:39.000Z"
  }
],
"OfficeContactPerson": [
  {
    "office": 1,
    "contact_name": null,
    "designation": "ASDF",
    "department": "234",
    "mobile": "1231231231",
    "email": null,
    "incharge_status": null,
    "created_by": null,
    "modified_by": null,
    "id": 1,
    "createdAt": "2016-04-15T08:41:08.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-04-16T14:18:39.000Z"
  },
  {
    "office": 1,
    "contact_name": null,
    "designation": "ASDF",
    "department": "ASDF",
    "mobile": "1231231231",
    "email": null,
    "incharge_status": null,
    "created_by": null,
    "modified_by": null,
    "id": 2,
    "createdAt": "2016-04-15T08:41:08.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-04-16T14:18:39.000Z"
  }
],
"OfficeBank": [
  {
    "office": 1,
    "bank": 2,
    "branch": null,
    "city": null,
    "account_type": 1,
    "ifsc_code": "12123",
    "account_number": "12234",
    "account_name": "asdfasd",
    "id": 3,
    "createdAt": "2016-04-16T14:18:39.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-04-16T14:18:39.000Z"
  }
],
"OfficeDocument": [
  {
    "office": 1,
    "document_original": null,
    "document_stored_name": null,
    "id": 1,
    "createdAt": "2016-04-15T08:41:08.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-04-16T14:18:39.000Z"
  }
],
"city": {
  "name": "Bengalore",
  "id": 1,
  "createdAt": null,
  "updatedAt": "2016-04-16T16:02:53.000Z"
},
"state": {
  "name": "Karnataga",
  "id": 1,
  "createdAt": null,
  "updatedAt": "2016-04-16T16:02:53.000Z"
},
"district": {
  "name": "BGL",
  "id": 1,
  "createdAt": null,
  "updatedAt": "2016-04-16T16:02:53.000Z"
},
"name": "kkk",
"short_name": "asdf",
"shop_no": "1",
"door_no": "11",
"floor": "1",
"building": "1",
"street": "1",
"area": "1",
"main": "1",
"pincode": "1",
"telephone": "1",
"hallmarking": null,
"payment_by": null,
"delivered_to": null,
"active_status": null,
"delete_status": null,
"created_by": null,
"modified_by": null,
"office_photo_original": null,
"office_photo_stored_name": null,
"cin_path": null,
"vat": null,
"pan": null,
"others": "123123",
"id": 1,
"createdAt": "2016-04-15T08:41:08.000Z",
"updatedAt": "2016-04-16T14:18:39.000Z"
 }
```

Comment: even though i have passed the null values in double quotes..still facing the same error

Answer (score 0):

the dictionary can't save null values.

Comment: This is not true you can add `[NSNull null]`, but you can not pas `nil`

Comment: @rckoenes dude, we have different terms in terms of semantics. i'm referring to the null as it is in the json and NOT the syntax in the iOS. also please take note that null in his post is NOT equal to the [NSNull null] object you are referring. you got to understand the context here.

Comment: Well `null` is also valid in JSON and will be parsed into `NSNull` by iOS. And then the you can check if the value for the key is equal to `NSNull`

Comment: did i say anything about null being not valid in json? im stating a general idea on what is causing his error. if you think you can spoon feed the answer to the question posted, why not post it? the idea that im stating on my post is plain. you said it yourself, you need to do a special handling and checking for the null values in json. it won't cut it just storing as it is in his case. see the point? just post a detailed answer if you think you have something to say.

Answer (score 0):

The `NSDictionay` format doesn't support null vales. Thats why its returning error.
The only possible solution for this is to update server database ,change null values to 0 or "NULL"(in double quotes). it will solve your issue.

Comment: want to change the null values in server database?